# How to test Data Bulid Tools(DBT) macros in DBT

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I have Data Build Tools (BDT) macro for Snowflake tables in aws and the snowflake table table name is source.customer. The macro is here:

```
{% macro get_customer(customer_status='active') -%}

 {{ source("source", "customer") }}
 WHERE 
 
{% if customer_status.lower() == 'active' -%}

     customerdesc = 'Existing' and customer_status = 0

{%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I add tests folder in dbt_project.yml file and create a test cases store under the tests folder. my test cases is here:

```
   {% test get_customer_active %}
expect query
with expected as (
    select 'Existing' as customerdesc, 0 as customer_status
)
{{ get_customer('active') }}
union all
select * from expected;
```

I run the test case at this command:

```
dbt test --select get_customer_active
```

The test run is success, and I get this message "The selection criterion 'get_customer_active' does not match any nodes"

Actually, the test case does not test the macor.

Question: How to test DBT macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following queries to verify the macro

```
select customer_status,customerdesc
from get_customer('status')
```

replace status with the following status

get_customer()

get_customer('any_string')

get_customer('active')

get_customer('ACtive')